# What would be an appropriate way of making an AI for Cell Machine?

Tags: deep-learning, deep-rl, training

The game Cell Machine is absolutely by itself not suitable for AI usage, but a certain niche within a mod of the game (Mystic Mod) known as "vaults" does seem like a suitable use case for AI. It involves making and solving vaults out of cells. It's entirely deterministic. These cells move in predetermined fashions each tick. The creator of a vault's goal is to to protect an enemy cell, and the solver wants to destroy this enemy cell. As the dataset for vaults and their solves is extremely small, this would have to be dealt with using self play. Could a framework like AlphaZero work, or would I have to build something from scratch? Note: Large Language Models surprisingly show some success at creating these vaults, but that would not be an improvable way.